# Use a Slide box (as in ionic framework) in Android Native App with ViewPager

Tags: android

I need to integrate a slide box type functionality (used/seen in ionic framework app) in native android app for which I think I need to use a ViewPager with a page indicator. I have tried dimajia slider, but I don't think I have control on its auto slide functionality. I need user to slide randomly and get intimated that slide is moving ahead with the pageindicator at below. I need to integrate it in my splash screen for once, before logging in.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit: I thought you wanted ionic help. Never Mind.

Comment: I am not building a cross platform app. I need to integrate in JAVA, whether there is a way or a library to achieve it?

Comment: Its ok Karan, not an issue. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Asked Android team, this should help you. http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

**activity_introduction.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.yourpackage.IntroductionActivity">

    <com.yourpackage.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/photos_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_relative" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/std_padding">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="@string/next" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**IntroductionActivity.java**

```
public class IntroductionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CustomViewPager viewPager;
    private Button nextButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introduction);
        //Initializing the tablayout
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.photos_viewpager);
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        //Creating our pager adapter
        IntroductionPagerAdapter introductionPagerAdapter = new IntroductionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(introductionPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);
        LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFERENCES_PATH", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    nextButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.i_agree));
                } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    nextButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.skip));
                } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putInt("KEY_INTRODUCTION_SKIPPED", 1);
                    editor.apply();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(IntroductionActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            finishAffinity();
        } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            nextButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.next));
        } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            nextButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.i_agree));
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_welcome.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_logo_round" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**WelcomeFragment.java**

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
    }
}
```

Similarly create two more fragments.

**IntroductionPagerAdaper.java**

```
public class IntroductionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    //private variable
    private int tabCount;

    //Constructor to the class
    public IntroductionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        //Initializing tab count
        this.tabCount = tabCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new WelcomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new DisclaimerFragment();
            case 2:
                return new RegistrationFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

**CustomViewPager.java**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }
}
```

Note: You can use default ViewPager unless you want to block its swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ViewPager** with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Then just check on which fragment (int index) you are, and use that to update the page indicator.

To know on which fragment you are add the following to the adapter:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Fragment> _pageReferenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();
```

in **getItem()** add

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    ...
    Fragment fragment = new myFragment();
    _pageReferenceMap.put(i, fragment);
    return fragment;
}
```

add this to **destroyItem(..)**

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    _pageReferenceMap.remove(position);
}
```

and finally add this method to know which fragment is currently in view

```
public myFragment getFragment(int key) {
    return (myFragment)_pageReferenceMap.get(key);
}
```

To call this method all you need to do is

```
int index = mViewpager.getCurrentItem();
myFragment fragment = profileAdapter.getFragment(index);
```